# web3.eth.Contract with Web3 1.3.0 does not seem to work

Tags: web3js

I'm able to create an instance of a smart contract that I know works in Ganache using Truffle.  But in my Javascript Nodejs app, with the syntax "let contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)", when I call the contractInstance method "contractInstance.ownerOf", it says "ownerOf" is not a function.  But I can see this in the ABI.  Also get an undefined when I console log "contractInstance.address".  Been "googling" this issue for hours and I'm coming up with nothing.  Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `contractInstance.contractMethod` is valid on web3.js v0.x.

Starting from web3.js v1.0, the syntax is `contractInstance.methods.contractMethod`.

And in order to get the contract instance address, you can use `contractInstance._address`.